# How to select latest entry per month, per year and per week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data table **history**. I wanna generate graphs for which i need,

1. Last entry for each day
2. Last entry for each week
3. Last entry for each month
4. Last entry for each year

to show values on graph based on selected period type.

With the following piece of sql code, I can fetch `last entry per day`.

```
SELECT t.created_on,
     t.earned_value,
     t.planned_value,
     t.budgeted_cost
FROM history t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.created_on) 'maxtimestamp'
FROM history tt
GROUP BY date(tt.created_on)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.created_on
```

How can I get the other three results?

Comment: Use `EXTRACT(WEEK FROM tt.created_on), EXTRACT(month FROM tt.created_on),EXTRACT(year FROM tt.created_on)` to group the results of your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this quite elegantly with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT created_on, earned_value, planned_value, budgeted_cost
FROM (
  SELECT created_on, earned_value, planned_value, budgeted_cost,
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY extract(year from created_on),
                                   extract(doy from created_on)
                      ORDER BY created_on DESC) r
  FROM history) sub
WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY created_on;
```

For the week and month time periods you can simply change the `extract(doy from created_on)` parameter into `extract(week ...` (doy = day of the year, counting from 1 January). For yearly data you need only the first `extract()` so you should delete the second `PARTITION` term.

Comment: I think this won't do the trick. if you change it for week, date 03.01.16 and 03.01.15 have the same value from extract(week from created_on). It will combine values from different time periods... The partition for weeks needs to also include month and year... partition for month has also to include year.

Comment: Good point, except that week data doesn't have to partition by month also because it gives the week number during the year. And changed 'day' to 'doy' to base that on the year too. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

`EXTRACT(WEEK FROM tt.created_on), EXTRACT(month FROM tt.created_on),EXTRACT(year FROM tt.created_on)` did the trick.

SO,

1- Last entry for each day

```
SELECT t.created_on,
 t.earned_value,
 t.planned_value,
 t.budgeted_cost
 FROM history t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.created_on) 'maxtimestamp'
FROM history tt
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tt.created_on)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.created_on
```

2- Last entry for each week

```
SELECT t.created_on,
 t.earned_value,
 t.planned_value,
 t.budgeted_cost
 FROM history t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.created_on) 'maxtimestamp'
FROM history tt
GROUP BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM tt.created_on)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.created_on
```

3- Last entry for each month

```
SELECT t.created_on,
 t.earned_value,
 t.planned_value,
 t.budgeted_cost
 FROM history t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.created_on) 'maxtimestamp'
FROM history tt
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tt.created_on)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.created_on
```

4-  Last entry for each year

```
SELECT t.created_on,
 t.earned_value,
 t.planned_value,
 t.budgeted_cost
 FROM history t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.created_on) 'maxtimestamp'
FROM history tt
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tt.created_on)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.created_on
```